# CSS | layer multiple centered divs in Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I would like 3 responsive columns in a section where the ".service-icon" are centered in each column. I have an image for the background of the column (dirtcolumn.png but this can be replaced by a full height div... all i want is it to be centered inside the div/column). You can see where the problem occurs on my first website in the first section under the cover ---->  [MOST RECENT SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDu3C.png)   -   http://aleven.netne.net/CDH/

HTML:  (after arranging every markup i could possibly think of which included giving all divs classes col-md-4 col-xs-4 ETC. ETC.)

```
    <section id="services">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="columndirt col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="service-icon">
    <div class="icon-daycare">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="columndirt col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="service-icon">
    <div class="icon-daycare">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="columndirt col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="service-icon">
    <div class="icon-daycare">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
#services {
background-color: #291501;
/*background-image: url(../images/cdh/newheader/ps/dirtcolumns.png);*/
padding: 0px 0;
padding-bottom: 0px;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center center;
position: relative;
min-height: 590px;
display: block;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;

}
.columndirt {

float: none;
margin: 0 auto;




background-image: url(../images/cdh/newheader/ps/dirtcolumn.png);
background-size: cover;

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 70% 100%;
top:0;
bottom:0;
max-height: auto;
max-width: 37%;
min-width: 37%;
background-position: center center;
text-align: center center;
vertical-align: middle;
position: absolute;


}
.service-icon {
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
margin: 158px;
margin-top: 180px;
border-radius: 100%;
background-color: #6d4827;
background-image: url(../images/cdh/newheader/ps/dots.png);
background-size: 1500px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 36px;
height: 170px;
line-height: 170px;
width: 170px;  
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
vertical-align: middle;


}
.icon-daycare {
vertical-align: middle;
color: #9f6c43;
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
background-image: url(../images/cdh/newheader/ps/daycareicon.png);
background-position: center center;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
}
```

Comment: I did not find any problem in the link you provide. Can you explain your problem with screen shot?

Comment: @MeFaysal I have updated with a screen shot. I would like the dirt columns to be centered behind the service icons. for some reason only one would show up or nothing at all.... i would like all 3.

Comment: Have you tried Bootstrap's `text-center` class on the same div as your `col-md-4`? It will center all content inside of the div.

Comment: you want something like this one? http://imgur.com/CXuMZBi

Comment: @MeFaysal close. i would like one more div/image inside of the circles. similar to the green house icon in my example. And i would like the white boxes to be full height of parent/section.

Comment: @Tricky12 Yes but it did not do anything. However, i removed the div="col-md-4" and placed the col-md-4 in the div="columndirt". As seen in the recently edited markup. This now places all of the columns directly behind each other instead of a grid. So it appears you only see 1 column because they are stacked.

Comment: I'm thinking it may be a positioning issue... but cannot figure it out... also text-center only makes it responsive for large/medium screen sizes.(changing to col-xs-4 didn't make a difference) The service icon div actually enlarges after a certain width and seems to pop out of the column class all together. RIP :/ yes ive checked all the responsive CSS to make sure nothing was countering.

Comment: Check this one. Don't worry about height or other things, let find the structure first. http://imgur.com/1eQy264

Comment: @MeFaysal more like the first one. This example is what you are looking for. sorry for confusion http://imgur.com/dOpzIBI . The white divs could even be full width if that would make it easier.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for. http://imgur.com/X3bED78

Comment: @MeFaysal yes. but i need the white boxes to be full height. Can be full width too but i would prefer 70% as seen in my markup.

Comment: Well, Div or section's height always depends on the contents height. But if you want to give it a height, you can use min-height or you can use contents padding. I am uploading my codes in the answer section. check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Div or section's height always depends on the contents height. But if you want to give it a height, you can use min-height or you can use contents padding. Change the padding and give the height you want.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="services">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="columndirt">
                            <div class="service-icon">
                                <div class="icon-daycare">
                                    <div class="box text-center"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="columndirt">
                            <div class="service-icon">
                                <div class="icon-daycare">
                                    <div class="box text-center"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="columndirt">
                            <div class="service-icon">
                                <div class="icon-daycare">
                                    <div class="box text-center"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- BEGIN LINK --><a href="https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.namecheap.com&#x2F;?aff=100108"><img src="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;files.namecheap.com&#x2F;graphics&#x2F;linkus&#x2F;200x200-4.gif" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt="Namecheap.com"></a><!-- END LINK -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>       
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#services {
    background-color: #291501;
    /*background-image: url(../images/cdh/newheader/ps/dirtcolumns.png);*/
    padding: 0px 0;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 590px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    //height: 500px;
}

.columndirt {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #fff;
}

.service-icon {
    float: none;
/*    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 158px;
    margin-top: 180px;*/
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #6d4827;
    background-image: url(../images/cdh/newheader/ps/dots.png);
    background-size: 1500px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 170px;
    line-height: 170px;
    width: 170px;  
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;

    margin: 100px 0;

}
.icon-daycare {
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #9f6c43;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/cdh/newheader/ps/daycareicon.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: green;
    margin: 25px 0 0 70px;
}
```